# Deprecated code examples in "Agile Web Development with Rails" - Don't know how to proceed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, scaffolding

I just started looking into Ruby on Rails and have been reading Dave Thomas's and DHH's "Agile Web Development with Rails." The book is from 2005, so a lot of the code and Terminal commands are outdated, but I have managed to reach page 57 without too much hassle. On page 57, I have created an app named "depot" using Rails and now they want me to use its scaffolding functionality by issuing the following command:

```
ruby script/generate scaffold Product Admin
```

Since that didn't work I figured the procedure has changed slightly within the last seven years, so it didn't take me too many Google searches before I (successfully) fired off this command instead:

```
rails generate scaffold Product Admin
```

This seemed to work. At least I got the list with the green "create" words in Terminal and a new controller and model was added to my app. Now, the step is to start the server (easy) and go to `localhost:3000/admin` but now I get the infamous `No route matches [GET] "/admin"` and I don't know why. I've uncommented `match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'` from routes.rb, but it still throws the same error.

What have I missed?

Comment: You would be better off going through the freely available [Rails Tutorial Book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) which is up-to-date, and is an awesome way to learn rails.

Comment: @PrakashMurthy Yep, that's the one I'm following, and it covers the latest and greatest.

Comment: @PrakashMurthy will definitely take a look at that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just need to add to your routes.rb:

```
get '/admin'
```

or

```
match '/admin' => 'admin#index'
```

Answer (score 0):

you use `scaffold` to create Product, Admin, the default url for you is `localhost:3000/products`, **plural**

Also, I would strongly recommend u get the latest version of the book.